# android studio how to change storage location of captured picture

Tags: android, storage, screenshot, preview

I want to know how to change storage location of captured picture.
In my codes, captured picture means screenshot image

Variable SendingImage get Bitmap, and then i want storing screenshot at sdcard or somewhere.
After store, i want get Uri about location of screenshot by String

Here is my code =

```
 File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


    String filename = "screenshot1.jpg";

    ImageView GetImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.show_heyboard);

    GetImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    Bitmap SendingImage;

    GetImage.buildDrawingCache();

    SendingImage = GetImage.getDrawingCache();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1_is working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    try{
        File files = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/sdcard");
        files.mkdirs();
        File f = new File(files, "screaanshot1");
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        SendingImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);

        outStream.close();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GetImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

If there is way to get preview of screenshot, Please tell me!!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how to change storage location of captured picture

You wrote the code that specifies the storage location:

```
File files = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/sdcard");
files.mkdirs();
File f = new File(files, "screaanshot1");
```

You are welcome to change that code to something else that suits your needs.

> If there is way to get preview of screenshot

Use [an image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), to load your image into an `ImageView`.